# Possible bug: panel not appearing in a status bar application launched at startup

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion

I fear that is a mountain lion bug.

The steps to reproduce it are:

- Create a status bar application;
- Add a menu item that triggers a method;
- In this method, show a window with orderFront: (window created through xib);
- Archive the application and add it as login item;
- Try to trigger the menu item and you'll see no window appearing.

To make this possibile, in the xib file I disable release when closed and visible at launch.

To make it show I have to launch again the application. I notice the same for applications installed from the app store like watts.

Comment: What do you mean by "Status Menu Application" and how do you show the window?

Comment: Status bar, corrected it. Like I said, I'm showing the window using the orderFront: method.

Comment: And this works under Lion?

Comment: The watts panel was showing under Lion, but with Lion I haven't tested other apps.

Comment: What is the "watts panel" and what has that got to do with your question?

Comment: This to say that also some apps installed from the app store present the same problem. To enforce the theory that it's a mountain lion bug. watts is a status bar application that works in a similar manner to mine.

Comment: Ah OK, that makes sense.  Perhaps contact the author of the "watts panel" and see what he has to say about it?  He might be of a mind to help you with your app.

Comment: Nice idea, I've just sent it.